# developing an anti-cheat search with proxy dll

Tags: dll, proxy, directx, heuristics, anti-cheat

There's a commom cheat program for a game.

I can make a proxy directx dll and inject any code i want in it.  should I scan the processlist and then try to find footprints?

someone point me in the direction of suitable heuristics?

Comment: I think this was done by putting d3d9.dll into your root? Just scan for it once in a while (while using a list of dll's that are fine) and throwing an error when it detects a proxy dll.

Comment: That would work but use more of the system machine than I would like to alter

Answer (score 1):

"Easiest" way to detect if it's a proxy or not would be to determine the path of the loaded d3d9.dll, calculate hash and compare it with stored hashes.